# TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my first javascript function for firebase.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

I got this error in firebase cloud function.How to resolve it?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    exports.grantSignupReward = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/last_signin_at')
      .onCreate(event => {
        const uid = event.params.uid;
        admin.database().ref(`users/${uid}/referred_by`)
          .once('value').then((data) => {
            var referred_by_somebody = data.val();
            if (referred_by_somebody) {
              var moneyRef = admin.database().ref(`/users/${uid}/earned`);
              moneyRef.transaction((current_value)=> {
                return (current_value || 0) + 10;
              });
            }
            return console.log('reddem updated')
          }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Got an error: ",error);
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cloud functions were updated, therefore you need to change this:

```
 exports.grantSignupReward = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/last_signin_at')
  .onCreate(event => {
    const uid = event.params.uid;
```

into this:

```
 exports.grantSignupReward = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/last_signin_at')
  .onCreate(snap,context) => {
    const uid = context.params.uid;
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

Comment: Thanks @Peter Haddad.I spent my whole day because of this.I don't know javascript.